# Youtrack integration with Gitlab behind LDAP authentification

Tags: version-control, gitlab, jetbrains-ide, youtrack

Youtrack 6.5 introduced integration with Gitlab VCS server.
I'm trying to integrate Youtrack 6.5 with stand-alone Gitlab repository (i.e. not gitlab.com)
Our Gitlab server also require users to go through LDAP authentification first. 
Is it possible to make Youtrack go through LDAP authentification?

Answer (score 0):

In case your LDAP server supports authentication with a client certificate, you can try adding a corresponding key to Hub as described here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/hub/2.0/Managing-SSL-Keys-and-Trusted-Certificates.html#ManagingSSLKeyStores and then select the key in GitLab properties form.